# Simple Python return "or" condition

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

I'm new at python 3.

in javascript this returns true if any of the conditions are true, otherwise it returns false

```
return condition1 || condition2 || condition3;
```

But in python this returns 
`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`
(n1 and n2 being ints)

```
return (n1==20) or (n2==20) or (sum(n1,n2)==20)
```

Is this just not possible in python or am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: `sum` take an *iterable*, not two ints.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `sum`; it takes only one argument that is iterable. Just make it a list/tuple:

```
return (n1==20) or (n2==20) or (sum([n1, n2])==20)
```

Or, considering you only have only two numbers, just do `n1 + n2`.

Comment: ... yeah or just use `n1 + n2`